# How to get parameter from angular get method in laravel?

Tags: laravel, angular7

I want to return user details from Laravel via Angular http.get() method, but its returning null from laravel.Everything is working fine except http.get() method.

**Angular code**

*app.component.ts*

```
this.userdetailservice.getuserdetails(44).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error) => {console.log(error); }
    );
```

*userdetailservice.ts*

```
url = 'http://localhost:8080/laravel_angular/blog/public/api/geteachuserdetail';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getuserdetails(id: any) 
    {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-type', 'Application/json');

    const myparams = new HttpParams();
    myparams.set('id', id);
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url, { headers: headers, params: myparams});
  }
```

**Laravel end**

*api.php*

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

   header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");

   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

   Route::get('/geteachuserdetail', "UserloginController@geteachuserdetail");
```

*UserloginController.php*

```
public function geteachuserdetail(Request $request) {

  $id=$request->input('params');

  echo json_encode(array('userdetail'=>$id));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
Route::any('/geteachuserdetail', "UserloginController@geteachuserdetail");
```

and

```php
public function geteachuserdetail(Request $request) {

  $id = $request->input('params');

  return response()->json(array('userdetail' => $id));

}
```

And you can try request you api with other tools like Postman, look the response code and the response content.

Comment: Not working.Still returning null. Its working for post request from angular but not working when I am writing http.get() in angular